Do I need to extract a source tar file for each pass in LFS, or does creating a seperate named "build" folder suffice (like "build", "build2")?
There's a handful of programs like GCC that not only require two different passes when setting up LFS, but as is the case with GCC, it is also used for Libstdc++.
When going thru this setting up for LFS, what is expected me of to do? The directions are somewhat vague on whether I should extract the source tar file into a different named folder for each pass, or if I should create a separate build folder inside the source folder for each pass (like "build", "build2")?
Also what would happen if I used the same build directory that was used in the original pass 1 but obviously configured differently for the second pass? Would there be any conflicts?

Toolchain Build

GCC requires the GMP, MPFR and MPC packages. As these packages may not be included in your host distribution, they will be built with GCC. Unpack each package into the GCC source directory and rename the resulting directories so the GCC build procedures will automatically use them
Note
There are frequent misunderstandings about this chapter. The procedures are the same as every other chapter, as explained earlier (Package build instructions). First, extract the gcc-14.2.0 tarball from the sources directory, and then change to the directory created. Only then should you proceed with the instructions below.

The Package Build Instructions clearly state (Specifically Item 3):


For each package:

a.)Using the tar program, extract the package to be built. In Chapter 5 and Chapter 6, ensure you are the lfs user when extracting the package.
Do not use any method except the tar command to extract the source code. Notably, using the cp -R command to copy the source code tree somewhere else can destroy timestamps in the source tree, and cause the build to fail.
b.) Change to the directory created when the package was extracted.
c.) Follow the instructions for building the package.
d.) Change back to the sources directory when the build is complete.
e.) Delete the extracted source directory unless instructed otherwise.

The same rules apply for every package in the toolchain, every time.  That means:

You configure and build PASS 1
You install PASS 1 in the /tools directory.
You DELETE Pass 1's build directory but keep the source tarball
You Configure, Build, and Install the API Headers in /mnt/lfs/usr/include, and Delete the Build
You Configure, Build, and Install GLIBC in /mnt/lfs, and Delete the Build
You re-extract the GCC tarball from Step 1 Above, Configure,  Build, and Install LibStdC in /mnt/lfs and Delete the Build.

You'll repeat Step 6 in Chapter 6 during Pass 2, i.e., extract the tarball, Configure, Build and Install per the directions, and then delete the build.
I've capitalized Configure, Build, Install, and Delete for a reason:
The Capitalized, pattern is the pattern to be used throughout the book, and memorizing it along with the repetition of doing it will help you understand what you're doing instead of just following along.

This is done so that your compile toolchain contains no traces of the hosts build tools, so that when you start Part 4 - Chapter 8, you are no longer relying on the host system's linker and other tools, and instead using the "clean toolchain" you built in Chapters 5, 6, and 7.

Once again, lesson learned! haha thanks bro. yeah i WAS reading the text but evidently not all of it. its hilarious i was doing this in a VM because I like running Windows at the moment. Shit ran so slow. Then I fired up an EC2 and my God it was like 100x faster. No kidding. But anyway, thanks man. I'll look at the text more and move on. Thanks again.

@watchy You're welcome. By the Way, watch the language.  Google redirects visitors here all the time, so the community frowns on foul language
